# enforce student to fill code inside a blank area in a function

Tags: c

I'm using a web based application to grade a C program submitted by a student.  For some questions, I would like the student to fill a code in a function.  The following is an example screen that the student will see.

```
go() {
---------------------------------
|                               |
|                               |
|                               |
---------------------------------
}

main() {
  go() 
}
```

The student should fill some code inside a box.  However, I don't want the student to create a new function like this:

```
go() {
---------------------------------
|  go_help();                   |
| }                             |
| go_help() { printf("hi"); }   |
---------------------------------
}

main() {
  go() 
}
```

How can I prevent the student to create a new function?  The code template together with the code filled by the student will be sent to the queue waiting to be compiled and run by the server.  I cannot change or check the code in that queue.  The only thing I can do is to change the code template.

Comment: Unless you want to write a C parser/compiler in Javascript, you're pretty doomed.

Comment: Do you need to prevent creating ALL functions or a particular one ?

Comment: If you cannot check the submitted code then you're out of luck. You'll need to make sure the submitted code is balanced in regards på {}, (), etc. This can only be done by analyzing the submitted code.

Comment: @0x69 I would like to prevent creating all functions.  I want the student to implement go().

Comment: This approach will allow the student to enter any code, including code to crash the program, fork the process, and possibly bring down your server.

Comment: You could always compile first and then perform static analysis using your function as a root. You can generate a call graph from this point (should have no outputs if the student did the assignment as you wanted).

Comment: BTW: Your example will not compile since the usercode is missing a `{` (or has a `}` to much actually).

Comment: Can you analyze the code after it has compiled? Or do you really only have the code template as an option? Before the assignment enters the queue can you analyze it there?

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve with this web stuff anyhow? A good teacher would do manual code review, because it is quite possible to reach the correct result using very bad or dangerous code, such as code relying on undefined behavior. (Or perhaps they try to write functions without return types, if they do, they should fail on any beginner C test.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think catching this at compile time will be very difficult (if not impossible). However, I you're willing to settle with a runtime error, the following might work (tested on GCC):

```
void go() {
---------------------------------
|                               |
|                               |
|                               |
---------------------------------
    //make sure nobody redefines __func__ ...
    #undef __func__
    //... and __builtin_strcmp
    #undef __builtin_strcmp
    //check if we're still inside go()
    assert(__builtin_strcmp(__func__, "go") == 0);
}

int main() {
    go(); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution.  If a student uses `#define __func__ "go"` , then `#undef __func__` can prevent a student to create a new function because __func__ will be undefined before the assertion.  However, the student can define another function `int strcmp(char* c, char* d) { return 0; }` and then he can create a new function.

Comment: @wannik: Yep you're right. I changed my answer to using `__builtin_strcmp` because GCC will always use its builtins even when the user redefines them.

Comment: Thank a million for `#undef` and `__builtin_strcmp`.  It really works.  But I'm concern whether `__builtin_strcmp` make a call to any other function that the student can redefine.

Comment: @wannik: I just ran a little test and `__builtin_strcmp` does not call any functions.

Comment: This is easy to work around: use the same trick as in the question, (define a whole bunch of functions and leave one open at the end), but make sure that the function you leave open is never called. Then the `assert` is never executed. Also, you don't stop the user from redefining `assert`.

Comment: @Steve: Yes I just realized the same thing could be done by just calling `exit` or returning from the function. We would need some way to assure the assert is executed and not redefined but I'm afraid it's just not possible...

Answer (score 2):

Can you put code in your template that will not be displayed in the web page?

If the user sees this:

```
void go() {
---------------------------------
|                               |
|                               |
|                               |
---------------------------------
}

int main() {
  go(); 
}
```

But their code is actually substituted into this:

```
void go() {
    int some_name_the_user_will_never_guess_123axpk = 1;
---------------------------------
|                               |
|                               |
|                               |
---------------------------------
    (void) some_name_the_user_will_never_guess_123axpk;
}

int main() {
  go();
}
```

Then it won't compile in the case where the user has closed the `go` function and opened another. Make sure it isn't compiled with the GNU extension for nested functions, though, or the user could define one of those.

You'd also have to conceal the compiler error message from the user, since it will contain the secret name.

[Edit: As a total bodge, if you define functions with every possible 1-character name except `g` at the start of the template, then call the function the user writes `g` instead of `go`, you could statically assert that `sizeof(__func__) == 2`. That means you can't be in a different function, because the user couldn't call it by a 1-character name.]

[Another edit: rats, that doesn't work either because the user could end their code with `#define sizeof(X) (X, 2)`, or `#define __func__ "g"`, or some such. That's not legal C, but it will in fact allow the user to cheat on pretty much any compiler. Preprocessors tend not to check that the tokens you use are unreserved names. Maybe if you do the static assert, and also do a bunch of checks that none of the tokens you use in that assert are defined as macros.]

Comment: I cannot hide the code but I like the idea of adding a secret name.

Comment: My other idea was to find a way of statically asserting, immediately after the user's code, that the current function name `__func__` is "go". But I can't think of a way of doing that, because `__func__` is the name of an array variable, it's not a string literal, so its value in effect isn't available at compile-time even though in fact it is of course known.

Comment: It works!  I'm thrilled by your solution.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Cool. Let me know if any of your students is smart enough to figure out a preprocessing trick to work around it, that I missed :-)

Comment: I just read your "Another edit".  If I assert `sizeof(__func__) == 2`, then the student can create a new function by `#define sizeof(__func__) 2`.

Answer (score 1):

When the student creates a new function, you will have unballanced curly brakets within the fill-in area: (at least) one extra closing one (to close the current function body) and (at least) one extra opening one (to start the new function body).  To figure out if this is the case, you need to check whether the curly braces are ballanced within the fill-in area, which you can only do by parsing the submitted text.

Comment: `go(){ go_help(); } void go_help(){ printf('help me!'); } void close_the_loose_brace(){ }` there doesn't need o be a unbalanced curly brace...

Comment: @RedX: `go() {` is not part of the usercode and will hence leave an unbalanced `}` in the usercode.

Comment: Ah ok, now i understood what he was talking about.

Comment: @Attila, I cannot parse the submitted text because I cannot modify the web application.  The only thing I can do is to write a code template.  The web form will submit the code template with the code filled by the user to the system to grade it.

Comment: @wannik: Then you're, as stated earlier, out of luck.